# Heroku uninstalling Pillow?

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I was getting the error n heroku when trying to upload a field:

**ModuleNotFoundError**

**No module named 'PIL'**

Full traceback:

```
2018-08-16T01:12:18.364616+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /admin/app/neighborhood/add/

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364628+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364630+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364632+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364634+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364635+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364637+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364639+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 607, in wrapper

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364642+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364644+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364646+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364647+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364649+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364651+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364653+00:00 app[web.1]:     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364654+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1647, in add_view

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364656+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364657+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364659+00:00 app[web.1]:     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364660+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364662+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364664+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1536, in changeform_view

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364665+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1568, in _changeform_view

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364668+00:00 app[web.1]:     form_validated = form.is_valid()

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364670+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364672+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.is_bound and not self.errors

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364673+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364675+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.full_clean()

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364677+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364678+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._clean_fields()

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364699+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 397, in _clean_fields

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364701+00:00 app[web.1]:     value = field.clean(value, initial)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364703+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 586, in clean

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364705+00:00 app[web.1]:     return super().clean(data)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364706+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 147, in clean

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364708+00:00 app[web.1]:     value = self.to_python(value)

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364709+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 615, in to_python

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364711+00:00 app[web.1]:     from PIL import Image

2018-08-16T01:12:18.364719+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

line 613 [of this django code is where the import of PIL is](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py)

I can go into heroku bash and import it (I guess it wasn't installed)

```
aiden@aiden-home:~/Desktop/dcre$ heroku run bash
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.7.4 to 7.7.10
Running bash on ⬢ protected-dusk-26749... up, run.3330 (Free)
~ $ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug  1 2018, 21:10:27) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>>> quit()

~ $ pip3 list
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
certifi          2018.8.13
dj-database-url  0.5.0    
Django           2.1      
django-heroku    0.3.1    
gunicorn         19.9.0   
pip              18.0     
pipenv           2018.5.18
psycopg2         2.7.5    
psycopg2-binary  2.7.5    
pytz             2018.5   
setuptools       40.0.0   
virtualenv       16.0.0   
virtualenv-clone 0.3.0    
wheel            0.31.1   
whitenoise       4.0      

~ $ pip3 install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/24/f53ff6b61b3d728b90934bddb4f03f8ab584a7f49299bf3bde56e2952612/Pillow-5.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 8.0MB/s 
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-5.2.0
~ $ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug  1 2018, 21:10:27) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> quit()
```

So I do  things, I 'restart all dynos', then I try and upload an image again. Same error

so I exit heroku bash, re-enter and

```
aiden@aiden-home:~/Desktop/dcre$ heroku run bash
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.7.4 to 7.7.10
Running bash on ⬢ protected-dusk-26749... up, run.3115 (Free)
~ $ pip3 list
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
certifi          2018.8.13
dj-database-url  0.5.0    
Django           2.1      
django-heroku    0.3.1    
gunicorn         19.9.0   
pip              18.0     
pipenv           2018.5.18
psycopg2         2.7.5    
psycopg2-binary  2.7.5    
pytz             2018.5   
setuptools       40.0.0   
virtualenv       16.0.0   
virtualenv-clone 0.3.0    
wheel            0.31.1   
whitenoise       4.0
```

My Pillow has been uninstalled somehow. Why is this happening

Comment: Do you have it in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I actually just figured it out - I am using heroku-django-template, which has a Pipfile (new way of pipping), b/c Pillow was not in my Pipfile, everytime I restarted heroku, it would wipe. I added Pillow = "*" to my Pipfile and works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just figured it out - I am using heroku-django-template, which has a Pipfile (new way of pipping), b/c Pillow was not in my Pipfile, everytime I restarted heroku, it would wipe. I added Pillow = "*" to my Pipfile and works now